# how to add my shared path as href in latex

Tags: hyperref

I want to add a hyper ref to a shared path ( \\LEUMWORK\Users\asadi\Desktop\examples ) in latex in windows. is there any idea?

Some thing like, "please see here!" and "here" is in Blue and address the to shared path.

```
\begin{frame}{}{}

\begin{itemize}
\item All examples can be found \href{\LEUMWOR\Users\hasadi\Desktop\examples}{here}. 
\item Feel free to add more!
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{\LEUMWORK\Users\asadi\Desktop\examples}{here is a link to a local file}.
\end{document}
```

You can look at [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks) to learn more about hyperlinks in tex documents.

Comment: I tried what you said, I got an error "! Undefined control sequence."

Comment: "I tried what you said": what does that mean? You copied that code in a new document, and tried to compile it with latex, in order to produce a pdf? What have you done exactly?

Comment: Mine is in the beamer, I will update the question.